# How does sitecore's treeviewex get associated with the javascripts?

Tags: javascript, treeview, sitecore, controls

I am currently trying to create a control in sitecore much like the treeviewex.

But its unclear to me how I would go about including javascripts like sitecore does.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate that very much, thank you :)

/Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own processor and add it into the `renderContentEditor` pipeline. You can find info and code in this blog post about [Adding custom Javascript and Stylesheets in the Content Editor](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/adding-custom-javascript-and-stylesheets-in-the-content-editor/)

Create a new processor class:

```csharp
public class InjectScripts
{
    private const string JavascriptTag = "<script src=\"{0}\"></script>";
    private const string StylesheetLinkTag = "<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";

    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        AddControls(JavascriptTag, "CustomContentEditorJavascript");
        AddControls(StylesheetLinkTag, "CustomContentEditorStylesheets");
    }

    private void AddControls(string resourceTag, string configKey)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(configKey, "Content Editor resource config key cannot be null");

        string resources = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting(configKey);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resources))
            return;

        foreach (var resource in resources.Split('|'))
        {
            Sitecore.Context.Page.Page.Header.Controls.Add((Control)new LiteralControl(resourceTag.FormatWith(resource)));
        }
    }
}
```

And then patch in the processor:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
     <pipelines>
       <renderContentEditor>
         <processor patch:before="*[1]" type="HideDependentFields.SC.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.InjectScripts, HideDependentFields.Types" />
       </renderContentEditor>
     </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping was possible, but didn't know how to go about, thank you.
I didn't want to alter any of sitecore's files, so this is perfect